# Google Places API in flutter mobile app Lat Lng problems

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

In a flutter app, I am using Google Places API for the following:
Autocomplete so users can type an address, then select the one they want from the suggestions. I then output the lat lng of that selected address in the backend and save them.

On Android, if a user selects "McDonald's, Fillmore Street, San Francisco, CA, USA", the lat lng that gets saved is: 37.779871299999996 -122.43171720000001

While on iOS if the user selects the exact same address of the same app built by flutter, using the same google API, the lat lng for this address "McDonald's, Fillmore Street, San Francisco, CA, USA" is: 37.8036218152837 -122.43683996363099
These last lat lng are completely wrong (1.5 miles away from the real location), and this is happening with almost all other address examples. I didn't set any specific paramaters to bias or to restrict searches, all settings are exactly the same.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Does it do it only on iOS notch devices - i.e. does it work correctly in an iPhone 8 simulator? I'm seeing something strange in our app with Google Maps lat/lng on iOS that only started happening recently and maybe it's related. I have Google Maps (GM) view, that I hide to get a lat/lng from another view, and re-show the GM view handing it the lat/lng position. It works fine on Android and non-notch iOS devices, but on iOS notch devices the map is offset vertically and it returns the wrong/different lat/lng. The offset seems to be screen-space related and is only vertical.

Comment: @Pat9RB thanks for the input. Today we found out that the issue is mainly at the establishment level: if we filter out the establishment, all remaining addresses are exactly the same on ios and android (for example highways, building numbers, streets). But if we search for restaurants or schools or any other establishment, even if the addresses are insterted exactly the same as described above, this is where the lat lng become different between ios and android. Any idea why this would happen?